# How can I select an option by default in HTML forms by knowing the option value which is to be selected using only HTML?

Tags: html, forms, html-select

Suppose I have an HTML Form which contains a drop down (and a submit button), through which a user can select any one of the unit of length and submit the form. The code for the drop down menu is show below :

```
    <select name = "from_length">
      <option value = "choose_1">Metre</option>
      <option value = "choose_2">Kilometre</option>
      <option value = "choose_3">Millimetre</option>
      <option value = "choose_4">Yard</option>
      <option value = "choose_5">Light Year</option>
    </select>
```

I want to select a default option which shall be displayed to the user, when the user opens the webpage.

However, there's a twist. I don't want to use the `selected` attribute in order to show a default option to the user. This is because the default option being displayed to the user may change depending on certain conditions (for e.g. when user selects "Kilometre" and submits this form, the user must see "Kilometre" selected by default, and not "Metre" (the first option)).

I wish to know if it is possible to select the default value based on the `value` of the option being selected by the user using **only** HTML (i.e. no JavaScript)

Thanks in advance for helping me out !

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see that you can do this is with PHP, which allows you to get access to form data. The file extension would also have to be changed from ‘html’ to ‘php’ for this to work.

```
<select name = "from_length">
   <option value="choose_1"<?php if($_POST["from_length"]=="choose_1"){echo(" selected");} ?>>Metre</option>
   <option value="choose_2"<?php if($_POST["from_length"]=="choose_2"){echo(" selected");} ?>>Kilometre</option>
   <option value="choose_3"<?php if($_POST["from_length"]=="choose_3"){echo(" selected");} ?>>Millimetre</option>
   <option value="choose_4"<?php if($_POST["from_length"]=="choose_4"){echo(" selected");} ?>>Yard</option>
   <option value="choose_5"<?php if($_POST["from_length"]=="choose_5"){echo(" selected");} ?>>Light Year</option>
</select>
```

My code still uses the `selected` attribute, but on each line, the php code checks if this option has been selected by the user, and only if it has, then the 'selected' attribute is printed into the document.